# Continue apt-get install package_list with not found packages

Tags: apt

I would like to run a non interactive package install that attemps to install the whole list:

```
apt-get -my install pkg1 pkg2 pkg3
```

for instance:

```
apt-get -my  install xosview mozilla-plugin-vlc sysvbanner
```

I need a command that continues even if there is an error when trying to install one of them.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make yourself a bash script to do so:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#Check whether root
if [ $(whoami) != root ]; then
    echo You must be root or use sudo to install packages.
    exit 1
fi

#Call apt-get for each package
for pkg in "$@"
do
    apt-get -my install $pkg
done
```

If the file is e.g. named `fail-ignore-apt.sh`, you could run it as:

```
sudo ~/fail-ignore-apt pkg1 pkg2 pkg3
```

assuming it's in your home directory. Remember to make it executable using:

```
chmod +x fail-ignore-script.sh
```